# I want to fetch a JSON from a website, but keep getting the 401 error

Tags: javascript, web, trello, trello-powerup

https://trello.com/1/boards/7AmLPD2t/cards?pluginData=true

I want to fetch the JSON in this URL, but I can't. Any help? I've tried most of the methods available on Stack Overflow already.

Answer (score 0):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_status_codes#4xx_Client_errors), you don't have the authorization. You should contact Trello or someone ho handle the trello side in your company.